# Function arguments as text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

this is my first post so please take it easy on me :)

I am trying to create a reusable function called alertControls(). I am trying to make the arguments bits that I can replace in the html strings called in the function but get an error when I try to do it like this. I have tried a few different ways but am puzzled why this wouldn't work in JS:

```
function alertControls(parent, icon, alert, message) {
  parent = "form-group has-warning has-feedback";
  icon = "warning-sign";
  alert = "warning";
  message = "Password too short";

  $(this).closest("div").removeClass();
  $('.alert').remove();
  $('span').not('.input-group-addon,.hidden-xs,.caret').remove();
  $(this).closest("div").addClass(parent);
  $(this).before('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-' + icon + 'form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
  $(this).closest("div").append('<div class="alert alert-' + alert + ' alert-strong is-attached"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></em> <strong>' + message + '</strong></div>');
}
```

Then I want to be able to reuse with different values in the function html:

```
alertControls("form-group has-error has-feedback", "error-sign", "error", "Not valid");
```

Many thanks for any help

Comment: *"but get an error"* And what is that error? What do you expect `this` to  refer to inside the function? In which context is the function called?

Comment: Remove parent="", icon="" ... This overrides the passed values

Comment: jsfiddle?? or any example with code..

Comment: @FelixKling - In the environment I am using it error is vendor.js:4311 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined and points to the function above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the element selector as an additional argument (make it the first):

```
function alertControls(selector, parent, icon, alert, message) {
  // define default values, but only use them when no value supplied:
  parent = parent || "form-group has-warning has-feedback";
  icon = icon || "warning-sign";
  alert = alert || "warning";
  message = message || "Password too short";

  // get element(s) for selector, and use that instead of `this`
  var $elem = $(selector);
  $elem.closest("div").removeClass();
  $('.alert').remove();
  $('span').not('.input-group-addon,.hidden-xs,.caret').remove();
  $elem.closest("div").addClass(parent);
  $elem.before('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-' + icon + 'form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
  $elem.closest("div").append('<div class="alert alert-' + alert + ' alert-strong is-attached"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></em> <strong>' + message + '</strong></div>');
}
```

call it like this:

```
alertControls("input#test", "form-group has-error has-feedback", "error-sign", "error", "Not valid");
```

You could alternatively look into creating a jQuery plug-in, and then you would use this syntax:

```
$("input#test").alertControls("form-group has-error has-feedback", "error-sign", "error", "Not valid");
```

But for this particular case I don't think it is that useful. jQuery plug-ins should not have dependencies like you have in your code, where it is expected that there is a parent `div`, and an element with class `alert`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @trincot that worked beatuifully, many thanks for everyone's help despite my some what lack of info, will try to post full code with jsfiddle examples in the future. :)

Answer (score 4):

1. You are assigning new values to parameters. If I've understood a problem, you should change it to:

`message = message || "Password too short";` and so on.

2. Your usage of `this` is incorrect. Maybe you have to pass another one attribute, say `element` and use it instead of `$(this)` so it would be:

   `if ($('input#test').val() === "" ) {
      alertControls($('input#test'), "form-group has-error has-feedback", "error-sign", "error", "Not valid");
   }`

Comment: This is not the main problem though

Comment: @trincot well... maybe. Its' unclear what `this` should be

Comment: Indeed, and the way the OP calls the function it is very unlikely that this improvement alone will make their code run.

Comment: @trincot you are right.
The function I am trying to make, I want to run in an IF statement and this would refer to an input that the IF statement condition contains e.g.
    if ( $(''input#test).val() ==="" ) {
    //function alertControls here
    }

Answer (score 0):

What you do:

```
function a(b){
 b=1;//overides b
 return b;
 }
 a(5);//returns also 1
```

You override the value of a.
Simply dont do this. If you want to have a standard value, that is used when no value is passed, you can use new ECMA6 syntax:

```
function a(b=1){
return b;
}
a();//returns 1
a(5); //returns 5
```

---

Problem 2:
"this" returns the parent object of a function. if you call your function inside js this will be the window object.

```
function a(){
 return this;
}
a(); //will return window
```

So you need to get the element another way, maybe passing it to the function or using:

```
$("#uniqueselector")
```